# Filling a an input based on another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to get the price of a product in one field when the name of the product is selected in another field for a simple POS. It works well for the first time but when I add another table row for next product, I don't get the price. Pls help

```
                   <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control itemNo" contenteditable="true"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control search_canteen_prod chk_product for_Price" autocomplete="off"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_1" readonly class="form-control changesNo price for_Price New_price" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo quantity" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="total[]" readonly id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice totalPrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Adding another row dynamically

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type= data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt itemNo" contenteditable="true"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control search_canteen_prod chk_product for_Price" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo price New_price for_Price" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo quantity" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice totalPrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly></td>';
    html += '</tr> <script>$( ".search_canteen_prod" ).autocomplete({source: "canteen/search_for_product.php"});</script>';
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});
```

Getting the price based on the autocomplete select

```
//get product prices
         $('.chk_product').on('change, keyup, blur', function() {

          iid_arr = $('.chk_product').attr('id');
          iid = iid_arr.split("_");

          var prodd_name = $('.chk_product').val();

        $.ajax({
           url:"canteen/select_for_canteen_sales.php",
           method: "POST",
           data:{prodd_name: prodd_name},
           dataType: "JSON",

          success:function(data)
          {
              $('#price_'+iid[1]).val(data.selling_price);

          }     }); });
```

fetching the price for

```
if(isset($_POST["prodd_name"]))
{

$prod_nm = $_POST["prodd_name"];
 $query_product = "SELECT * FROM canteen_product WHERE product_name = '". $prod_nm."' AND qty > 0 ORDER BY stock_date DESC";
 $result_product = mysqli_query($cnn, $query_product);
 while($rrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result_product))
 {

  $data["selling_price"]        = $rrow["selling_prce"];

 }

 echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:
If you use table length only after you add the next table row to generate `i`, it will be 1 for the very next table row you add...  becaue you already have one row (with the html ids being like `itemNo_1` etc).

Which means that your next-added row will also have the ids ending in 1.

To fix this, you should use `i + 1` in your `.addmore` function to the html-ids of any new table rows. so they start at eg `itemNo_2` adn then go up from there.

Secondly:

you can fetch values relative to the current object (accessed using `$(this)`) - you don't need to fetch them by id.
eg instead of:

```
$('.chk_product').on('change, keyup, blur', function() {
      iid_arr = $('.chk_product').attr('id');
      iid = iid_arr.split("_");
      var prodd_name = $('.chk_product').val();
```

try something like:

```
$('.chk_product').on('change, keyup, blur', function() {
  var prodd_name = $(this).val();
```

for the price - you can likewise do relative tree-traversal... eg if the price is always "up one to the td, then down to the price" you can do something like:

```
   //          chk_product-> td -> down to price value    
   var price =  $(this).parent().find(".price").val();
```

Note: you will need to bug-test this and I recommend looking up the docs for how it works.